# Merge two arrays but in specific order in javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm tryin' to explain what i want. I have two arrays:

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
my_array_two = ["string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string" ];
```

and i need to merge this arrays but in a specific way. The new array will be:

```
my_new_array = [1, 2, "string", 3, 4, "string", 5, "string", 6, "string", 7, "string", 8, "string", 9, "string", 10, "string", "string", "string" ]
```

The arrays length can be from 1 to 10.
I can't figure out how can i do this, i hope some help for this task.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a pattern here? I seem to be drawing a blank.

Comment: You'll need to spell out the pattern more clearly, a process that will probably provide you with the information you need to code a solution for yourself. If the arrays can have a length "from 1 to 10" what happens if they're not the same length?

Comment: Sorry, yes there is a pattern, it's something like this:
I tried with slice() inserting the elements from my_array_two into the first array, 
and the pattern is(by the index of the first) 2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only pattern I can deduce from the specific input and output shown is to take two values from the first array, then one value from second array, then again two from the first, then alternate one from each until all values have been used from both arrays.

If that's right then the following code will do it:

```
// copy first input array into output array
var my_new_array = my_array.slice(0);    
// loop over second array
for (var i = 0, j = 2; i < my_array_two.length; i++){
    // insert next item into output at position j
    my_new_array.splice(j, 0, my_array_two[i]);
    // figure out next position to insert    
    j += (j < 4) ? 3 : 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn this is exactly what i want, sorry if i wasn't too much clear

Answer (score 0):

If this is an original algorithm, your best best would be too write your own sort algorithm to merge the two.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the specific pattern is, but as far as the basic algorithm, I would recommend something like this:

```
var combined_array = [];
var index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
while ((index1 < my_array.length) && (index2 < my_array_two.length)) {
    if (/*you're at the end of either array*/) {
        // take the next element from the other one.
    }
    else {
        if (compare(my_array[index1], my_array_two[index2])) {
            combined_array.push(my_array[index1]);
            ++index1;
        }
        else {
            combined_array.push(my_array_two[index2]);
            ++index2;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `compare` is some function you write that looks a both values and returns true if the first one should come before the second.